# drupal 6 cck format in custom template file

Tags: drupal-6, cck

i'm creating a custom .tpl file for a node type with some cck fields.
In de cck module i selected a integer format style for a field.
Now in the tpl i load the field from the $node object but it's without format (9999 in stead of 9.999).

In the $node object you have an item '#theme' and '#formatter', i guess i need one of these but how?
i tried the theme() function but then it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've used content_view($node); to 'render' all the values.
Putting this on the top of the page gave me an array with all the right (themed) values.